# What is the origin of face 'turning around'?

Tags: etymology, phrases

I'm watching a documentary movie on the history of Roman Empire. There's a part where the narrator says "In 113 BC, the Roman General Carbo parleyed for peace with the barbarians. Then he turns around and murders their ambassadors."

Meanwhile in the enactment the actor playing Carbo actually 'turns around', faces to the opposite side towards his soldiers and signs them to ambush and kill the opposite party when they are gone.

Has this phrase 'turning around' got some significance more than the literal meaning?

Comment: The idiom is _(and) (then) turn(s)/turned/turning around and_ `VP`, where `VP` is a verb phrase in the same tense as _turn_. It means to be expected to do something, and then to immediately confound the expectation by doing something completely different. The _turn around_ part refers to the contradiction, and has no other meaning.

Answer (score 1):

As John Lawler pointed out, *turn* is at the root of many idioms. So is *face*.

When someone does an *about face*, it is an abrupt change of opinion or behavior, a 180° turn, derived from the military command.

*two faced* means a person acts a certain way in one place and acts different in another.

A *turncoat* is a traitor.

A *heel-face turn* is when a bad guy turns good.

In wrestling (professional), a *face* is a good guy. A *heel* is a bad guy. Some *faces* may resurrect their popularity by doing a *face turn*, that is, become a bad guy. The opposite also applies.

A *turnaround* is a complete change from one way of thinking to an opposite way of thinking (or bad fortune to good).

So *turn around* implies a deception, a double-cross, and here the concept is actually played out, demonstrated by the General physically turning around.

This kind of physical 'play on words' is often done on the History Channel, which has limited funds and uses as little actual activity or filming as possible to get their point across.

Comment: You've got "face turn" and "heel turn" reversed: the term "face turn" describes a heel "turning face", i.e. a bad guy becoming a good guy.